# Compile AspectJ code to Java 6 code with a AspectJ 1.7 installation

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I am developing using Eclipse 4 and AspectJ's latest version. I am in the process of replacing a Java 6 library with a modified one (binary weaving). The problem is that the code being currently woven is Java 7 code, and I need it to be Java 6 code.

I know there is an AspectJ's compiler switch, but I'd like to know if it's possible to set that setting through Eclipse (other than using an Ant task, of course).

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up downloading AspectJ 1.6. I then switched to the `JRE6`, added `aspectrt.jar` from the AspectJ 1.6 installation (as I needed it to be included in the generated binary woven jar) and set the Java Compliance Level to 1.6.

It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In you Eclipse project settings under "Java Compiler" -> "Compiler compliance level" you can set the compliance level to 1.6.

Under "AspectJ Compiler" -> "Non-standard compiler options" you can set the "-6" switch (synonyms are "-6.0" and "-1.6").

Comment: but i'll still need to use aspectjrt.jar from a aspectj 1.6 version, right?

Comment: I have not tried. But why should you if you use the 1.6 switch of ajc? Give it a try and let me know if it works out. Good luck. I am on the road and cannot try for myself now.

Comment: because at runtime you'll need to put aspectrt.jar in the classpath, and if your jre is set to 1.6, then it won't like having a 1.7 jar in its classpath.

Comment: I use AspectJ 1.7.x runtime with JRE 6 all the time.